# Find multiple subdocuments match in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

i cannot find anything related to that.

I need to find(ON METEORJS MONGO, WHO DONT HAVE AGGREGATION), some subdocuments, the rule to that is, if type is equal to 2, get these subdocument.
The problem is, on server we have projection ($) and ($elemMatch) operator, but these give only the first match subdocument and i need all the subdocuments who have these value.

The example document

```
"Users":{
   "Example" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "1",
        "title" : "All Included",
        "_id" : "11a4e0ab6f136ddc8870dc95"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "2",
        "title" : "Other sub",
        "_id" : "123asddc8870dc95"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "2",
        "title" : "More type 2",
        "_id" : "cxzcasdo2"
    }, 
   ]
}
```

But when i do the

```
var data = Users.find({'Example.type':'2'}, {fields:{'Example.$':1}});
```

The returned values is only the first matched element _id = 123asddc8870dc95 and not the two how has type 2.

I have no idea how to do that, Meteor dont have aggregation and i cannot do a map before publish to find all subdocuments and remove mannualy.

:/

Edited:

I know that meteor has a hack to do aggregation, but i dont want to use this, to avoid dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation with meteor using meteorhacks:aggregate. Here's a [tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/aggregations-in-mongodb/).

Since you don't want to use another package, you can access the raw collection using:

```
myCollection.rawCollection()
```

I believe rawCollection will have the aggregate function on it as well.

Comment: I dont want more dependencies on my project, do you know another form to make this without these hack?

Comment: You can access the rawDatabase using collection.rawDatabase().  You should also be able to do aggregation from there.

Comment: Do you have some example or documentation? I dont find rawDatabase related to meteorjs

Comment: I would like to know if `$in`  opertor does any trick here .Thanks